# How to Sync The Silverlight and Web Projects

Tags: silverlight, web, installation

In my Silverlight solution I have a edsv project and a edsv.web project. If I make edsv the startup project it works ok. If I make edsv.web the startup project, it executes a much earlier version of the code. 
The setup project need to use the .web project, right? So my install kit reflects the wrong code. How do I get the projects in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution in another forum, please see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/8293acb7-a2dc-4c04-92f7-150830cc355a/how-to-sync-the-silverlight-and-web-project

Bob